# delete rest api to remove statements from global context

Tags: sparql, sesame

I send the following http request to Sesame Server:

```
params = { 'subj' : '?s', 'pred' : 'rdf:type', 'obj' : 'Device' }
```

Also tried:

```
params = { 'pred' : 'rdf:type', 'obj' : 'Device' }
```

which translates to:

http://example.com/openrdf-sesame/repositories/devices/statements?pred=rdf%3Atype&subj=%3Fs&obj=Device

I perform following operation on params in PYTHON:

```
 urllib.urlencode(params))
```

I get Response: 400 (Bad Request).

Please help resolving this issue. I think its related to improper encoding of predicate URI. The prefix is: '`<http://example.com/devices#>`'

Reference:

http://www.openrdf.org/doc/sesame2/system/ch08.html#d0e341

Comment: could you please help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide full URIs for the request parameters. Prefixed names are not allowed. The full URIs should be in N-Triples encoded form (that is, enclosed in angle brackets).