# MALFORMED QUERY: Encountered " "delete" "DELETE

Tags: sesame

While trying to delete triplets I get following error:

```
MALFORMED QUERY: Encountered " "delete" "DELETE 
Was expecting one of:
    "base" ...
    "prefix" ...
    "select" ...
    "construct" ...
    "describe" ...
    "ask" ...
```

My query was:

```
DELETE {
  ?s example:id 'Id' .
};
```

Sesame with Jetty is what I am using. I sent an HTTP request. I have another question opened around this

[delete rest api to remove statements from global context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17740499/delete-rest-api-to-remove-statements-from-global-context)

I might be sending to wrong endpoint. My endpoint looks like:

http://example.com/openrdf-sesame/repositories/$repo/

Please help.

EDIT:

```
    self.baseURLRepositories = storeUrl + "/openrdf-sesame/repositories/"

endpoint = self.getBaseURLForSesameRepositories() + "%s" % (self.getRepository())
params = { 'query': query }
headers = {
  'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
  'accept': 'application/sparql-results+json'
}
(response, content) = httplib2.Http().request(endpoint, 'POST', urllib.urlencode(params), headers=headers)
results = json.loads(content)
```

where query = DELETE ...

Comment: I think I figured out. I needed to use update instead of query. But please verify if you can.

Answer (score 1):

You are using an incorrect endpoint location. SPARQL update requests should be sent to `openrdf-sesame/repository/<repid>/statements`.