# SPARQL delete on owlim-lite not working

Tags: java, sparql, sesame

I want to delete all the triples in my OWLIM-lite store using Java/Sesame API

I tried:

```
DELETE WHERE { ?s ?p ?o } ;
```

in all variants (with or withour prefixes) like so:

```
DELETE * WHERE { ?s ?p ?o } ;
DELETE { ?s ?p ?o } WHERE { ?s ?p ?o } ;
WITH <...> DELETE * WHERE { ?s ?p ?o } ;
...
```

but none of these queries seem to work. I always get the same exception:

```
org.openrdf.query.MalformedQueryException: Encountered " "delete" "DELETE "" at line 1, column 1.
Was expecting one of:
    "base" ...
    "prefix" ...
    "select" ...
    "construct" ...
    "describe" ...
    "ask" ...
```

It looks like it's a similar problem as this one: [MALFORMED QUERY: Encountered " "delete" "DELETE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17770420/malformed-query-encountered-delete-delete) except all the other queries (SELECT) work perfectly fine.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Which version of OWLIM are you using?

Comment: I'm using version 5.4

Comment: This sounds like you are trying to make an update through an API that only expects queries, note that SPARQL Query and Update are separate languages and typically have separate APIs for invoking them.  Please show your code that invokes the update otherwise we can't help you further

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably using an incorrect endpoint location for your updates. SPARQL *update* requests should be sent to `openrdf-sesame/repository/<repid>/statements`, while SPARQL *query* requests should go to `openrdf-sesame/repository/<repid>`.

Comment: Please, @Jeen Broekstra, what do you mean by "...SPARQL update request should be sent to openrdf-sesame/repository/<repid>/statements..." I have been having that same issue all day and can't figure out why I am having the same error. Please, explain more if possible with a code. Thanks

Comment: @helpdesk, the endpoint URL is the web address to which a SPARQL request is sent. In Sesame, update requests go to a different URL than query requests. I'm half-suspecting you are using the Workbench application though, in which case the problem is simply that you are using the wrong form: there's a separate option in the Workbench for doing updates, it should not be done in the Query form.

If this doesn't sufficiently clarify it, I suggest you post a new question with exact details of what you're trying to do (and _how_ you do it).